# Checking percentage of free memory using top and awk

Tags: bash, linux, awk

The following Awk code was created in order to verify if free memory from the top command is less than 20% of the total.

I've noticed that I actually do not need the `top -n1 | grep Mem |`, because the `FREEM` and `TOTALM` parameters are inside the third `awk` line.

But on the other hand, I could not run the Awk as:

```
 awk -v FREEM=$FREE_ME MORY -v TOTALM=$TOTAL_MEMORY '{per=int(FREEM)/int(TOTALM)*100; if(per<=20) print "FAIL" ; else print "OK"}'
```

My current code is:

```
 TOTAL_MEMORY=` top -b -n1 | grep Mem: | awk '{print $2}' `

 FREE_MEMORY=` top -n1 | awk -v RS="[, ]" '/free/{print a}{a=$0}' | head -1 `


 top -n1 | grep Mem | awk -v FREEM=$FREE_MEMORY -v TOTALM=$TOTAL_MEMORY '{per=int(FREEM)/int(TOTALM)*100; if(per<=20) print "FAIL" ; else print "OK"}'
```

I have a feeling that this code is ugly because of the `top -n1 | grep Mem |`.  Are there any suggestions on running the `awk` without it?

Comment: THX Jamal on your update -:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my test system, the output of `top -b -n1 | head` looks like this:

> ```
> top - 09:33:08 up 9 days, 23:07,  7 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.10, 0.13
> Tasks: 125 total,   1 running, 124 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
> Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
> Mem:   4054892k total,  3938964k used,   115928k free,       56k buffers
> Swap: 10485756k total,   536176k used,  9949580k free,   438836k cached
>
>   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S   %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
>     1 root      20   0 10548   36    8 S      0  0.0   0:02.69 init
>     2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:00.06 kthreadd
>     3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:01.22 ksoftirqd/0
> ```

I suppose yours is similar.
From your code it looks like you are extracting the values from the `Mem:` line,
in this example `4054892k` and `115928k`.
Those values are in the 2nd and 6th column (in Awk terms), so you can get them easily in one command with:

```
top -b -n1 | awk '/^Mem:/ {total=int($2); free=int($6);}'
```

Now it's easy to add the percentage calculation and print the result:

```
top -b -n1 | awk '/^Mem:/ {total = $2; free = $6; per = free / total * 100; print per <= 20 ? "FAIL" : "OK"; exit}'
```

Some additional points of interest:

- After printing, we `exit` to stop processing unnecessarily the rest of the output coming from `top`
- The ternary operator `?:` can simplify the printing, no need for an if-else
- I dropped the `int(...)` calls, as Awk seems to drop the trailing non-numeric values anyway
- The pattern `/^Mem:/` is more strict than in the original code, just to be safe

**UPDATE**

If you the position of free memory can be in different columns depending on the system, you have (at least) 2 options to work around that:

1. If you can know the position in advance (by detecting based on the system / runtime environment), you could pass that in as a variable, for example:

   ```
   i=6; top -b -n1 | awk -v i=$i '/^Mem:/ {total = $2; free = $i; per = free / total * 100; print per <= 20 ? "FAIL" : "OK"; exit}'
   ```
2. Or, you could use regular expressions, for example:

   ```
   top -b -n1 | awk '/^Mem:/ {total = $2; match($0, /[0-9]+[a-z] free/); free = substr($0, RSTART); per = free / total * 100; print per <= 20 ? "FAIL" : "OK"; exit}'
   ```

Comment: I cant use $2 and $3 because the values change the position some times we see the free memory in $6 and some time on $8 this is the reason that I use external values

Comment: See my updated post for possible workarounds for such case. There can be others too. Either way, a single `awk` can handle this.

Comment: OK I will check that on my machine,

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `top`, which us meant to be used s an interactive display, you should use the `free` command, which outputs the same two rows of headers that you want.

However, I would question the motivation behind this code. Why is it important to check the amount of free memory?  On any modern general-purpose operating system, free memory is considered wasted memory — a resource that could be better used for caching disk data, for example.